# Facing issue to run VBA functionality in MacBook

Tags: iphone, vba, macos

Using Mac book performing operation on Excel.

From MVC application downloading excel template and performing operations. This I can do it successfully in Windows, but not in Mac book. Facing issue 'Method or data member not found" while opening excel sheet.

Comment: If you want help with code, you're going to need to post the code. VB6 doesn't exist on Mac, so I suspect that's not the language you mean. (There are a lot of languages that start with "VB" which are slightly or not-so-slightly different.) Also, how does the [tag:iphone] tag apply?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Are you sure Windows VB Excel macros not supported to Mac Excel macros?

Comment: This question was initially tagged as [tag:VB6], though VB Excel macros aren't the same thing. Some versions of Excel have VBA with similar (though slightly different) functionality. I don't know how or if VBA or Excel macros work on Mac, I just know that VB6 doesn't. It looks like somebody changed the wording and tagging to be [tag:vba] instead, which might be what you're looking for. In any event, saying that your code has a method that isn't found, without posting that code and what method it is that isn't being found, makes it difficult to know what help you are looking for.